# How to calculate value of R2 in this circuit?

Tags: current, resistors, theory

[image]

I'm reading a Floyd electronics book and working through some problems. This one has me stumped however. I already know the answer as it's given in the book (110k). However, I don't know how to actually solve the problem. I've tried approaching it from a few different angles, but none of them seem to work as I'm always short of a variable. Can anyone advise?

Comment: 1) Write out all the equations. 2) Substitute until you have a single unknown. 3) Solve for that unknown. 4) Go back to step 2 until you're out of unknowns.

Comment: I've tried that, but I always seem to have more than one unknown. I've tried the current divider formula, but I'm short of both Itotal and R2. I can't calculate the voltage across any of the resistors either as I don't know the total resistance.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you write all the equations you've found in the circuits?

Comment: It's OK, I've got it now. The problem initially appeared to be a catch-22 as there was so much information 'missing'. I knew that if I had the total current, I could use KCL and get the current through R1 and thus the voltage. Likewise, if I knew the voltage across R3, I would know the voltage across R2 from KVL. The problem is that I didn't know how to find any of them. Once I've got the current through R1, it's trivial to solve.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv5HTf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the top resistors (all resistances calculated in 'k'):
$$ V_1 = 47 x  \tag 1 $$

For the bottom resistor:
$$ V_3 = 33 (x + 1) \tag 2 $$

From voltage drop across R1 and R3:

$$ V_1 + V_3 = 220 \tag 3 $$

$$ 47x + 33 (x+1) = 220 \tag 4 $$

$$ 80x = 220 - 33 \tag 5 $$

$$ x = \frac {187}{80} \tag 6 $$

Now you can work out V1 and therefore R2.

Comment: Thanks for your time on this. I didn't realise that it was just basic algebra. Perhaps I over-analysed the problem as usual.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the same schematic, drawn a little differently:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbKFIC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You know that \$V_X=R_3\cdot I_3=R_3\cdot\left(I_1+1\:\textrm{mA}\right)\$.

Moving \$V_X\$ downward means less current in \$R_3\$ but also more current in \$R_1\$ that needs to go through \$R_3\$. Moving \$V_X\$ upward means more current in \$R_3\$ but also less current in \$R_1\$ to support that need for current in \$R_3\$. So this suggests that there is some middle value of \$V_X\$ that will be "just right."

A moment of thought and I think you also know that the current in \$R_1\$ is \$I_1=\frac{220\:\textrm{V}-V_X}{R_1}\$. That gives you the two bits of information you need.

Can you solve it now?

Comment: Yes, I understand now and I can derive the proper answer from the previous example given. It was the initial stage of finding I1 that I couldn't solve. R2 is easy to work out once I've got that. It was more a failure at basic maths than electronics.